# The member functions of my class aren't working properly. Any idea why?

Tags: c++

I made a linked list class to practice generic programming. The following code compiles, but my test in the main isn't printing anything to the console, like it should be. Any idea why? I know that Stack Overflow doesn't like the "fix my bug" posts, but I'm really at a loss here.

```
#include <iostream>

template <class T> class List { 

public: 
    List();
    ~List();
    int getSize();
    void push_back(T);
    bool contains(T);

private:
    struct node { 
        T val;
        node* next;
    };
    int size;
    node* firstNodePtr;
    node* lastNodePtr;

};

template <class T> List<T>::List() { 
    size = 0;
    firstNodePtr = NULL;
    lastNodePtr = NULL;
}

template <class T> List<T>::~List() { 
    node* curNodePtr = firstNodePtr;
    node* nextNodePtr;
    while (curNodePtr) { 
        nextNodePtr = curNodePtr->next;
        delete curNodePtr;
        curNodePtr = nextNodePtr;
    }
}

template <class T> int List<T>::getSize() { 
    return size;
}

template <class T> void List<T>::push_back(T newElement) { 
    if (size == 0) {
        firstNodePtr = new node;
        firstNodePtr->next = lastNodePtr;
        firstNodePtr->val = newElement;
        ++size;
    } else { 
        node* newNode = new node;
        lastNodePtr->next = newNode;
        newNode->val = newElement;
        newNode->next = NULL;
        ++size;
    }

}

template <class T> bool List<T>::contains(T thisElement) { 
    node* curNodePtr = firstNodePtr;
    while (curNodePtr) { 
        if (curNodePtr->val == thisElement)
            return true;
        curNodePtr = curNodePtr->next;
    }
    return true;    
}

int main (int argc, char* const argv[]) {

    List<int> myList; 
    myList.push_back(5);
    myList.push_back(18);
    std::cout << myList.getSize() << std::endl;
    std::cout << myList.contains(18);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: When you say it doesn't print anything, does it not even print a newline?

Comment: What specific problem are you having with your debugger?

Comment: Unhandled exception at 0x00B244E2 in test.exe: 0xC0000005: Access violation writing location 0x00000004.

Is what you get from compiling that.

Comment: unrelated: the second `return true;` in `contains()` should be `return false;`. And that function should be `const`.

Answer (score 0):

Look here:

```
if (size == 0){
  firstNodePtr = new node;
  firstNodePtr->next = lastNodePtr;
  firstNodePtr->val = newElement;
  ++size;
}
```

You forgot to assign a value to `lastNodePtr`. So when you try to dereference it in the second call to `push_back`, you get undefined behavior.

Answer (score 0):

In the block handling the creation of the initial node in `push_back`,
you don't want this line:

```
firstNodePtr->next = lastNodePtr;
```

Also, you need to set `lastNodePtr = firstNodePtr;` at the end of `push_back`